# Split an associative array with > sign and display it in list ion php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I developed a sql table in which i am putting details related to products which are in my feed file.There is a field in sql table by the name of categories which is in format of category1>category2>category3.I want to split this column with > sign and display it in a list.

For now i m putting them in an associative array,But i dont know how to split the category element of the array and display it in list.

```
<?php
$firstsql='SELECT TOP 1 from xml where ('.implode('AND',$parts).')';
$firstsql3=mysql_query($firstsql);
$firstrow=array();  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstsql3)) {
    // Append to the array
    $firstrow[] = $row;     
    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}
```

Above is the snippet where i m putting the top first row in array from where i have to get the category element of array and display it in list.
Like category column in array is like MEN>CLOTHING>SHOES
i want to dispay it like

```
MEN
CLOTHING
SHOES
```

Please guide me how to do this..

Comment: You should really look into normalizing your database / using a separate table for your categories and a table to link them to the products.

Comment: Means You are saying i should create two column s one with category and one with subcategory and then i should display them in my required manner.is it?

Comment: TOP is not a mysql function/operator !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood, you can do

```
$categories = explode(">",$row["category"]);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    // Do what you need with each $category, it will be "MEN", "CLOTHING" and "SHOES" each time
}
```